# Set String Array to ImageView

Tags: android, arrays

I want to set String Array that contain images position to ImageView. The String Array is passed back Activity A to Activity B and set to ImageView in Activity B.
How I should set? Below are the codes :

From Activity A :

```
 String[] outputStrArr = new String[selectedItems.size()];

                    for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
                        outputStrArr[i] = selectedItems.get(i);
                        //Log.i(GalleryActivity.TAG,outputStrArr[i]);
                    }

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            MainActivity.class);

                    // Create a bundle object
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putStringArray("gridItem", outputStrArr);

                    // Add the bundle to the intent.
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);

                    // start the MainActivity
                    startActivity(intent);
```

From Activity B:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bundle != null){

        String[] result = bundle.getStringArray("gridItem");

        if(result != null){;
            // I want to set the String Array to ImageView here. 
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Define "contain images". What's inside the array, put an example. We don't know if you don't show

Comment: Do you know the position that you need to put it in an imageView from that array?

Comment: @JuanCortes my images are loaded from sdcard and display in gridview. I had selected few images from gridview and send to another activity which contain an imageView. The problem is how to set the array of images into that imageView after bundle.getStringArray("gridItem"); ?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First the image needs to be included inside drawable folder, then here what you can do:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String mDrawableName = result.get(position);;
int resID = res.getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(resID );
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable );
```

This should work perfectly. But let me know if you have another issue.

EDIT:

Try the below code to set Bitmap images from a file stored inside a SD-Card:

```
File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/Images/my_image.jpg");
if(imgFile.exists()){
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}
```

And include this permission in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: But my images are from loaded from sdcard and display inside gridview. After I get multiple selected item and store into string array and pass to another activity (Activity B) and set that multiple image into imageView.

Comment: By logging the variable " result " of string array.,I clearly see the displayed number of selected item in logcat which means the selected item was successfully retrieved from Activity A

Comment: So you want to display an image from your SD card to your imageView? do you know the path position?

Comment: I'm using  Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageID + "");
to get the images from Sdcard and display in gridview. The images were successfully displayed in gridview. Now I select multiple images from GridView and store the image position into string array and send to another activity. Is it correct to store image position into string array or store image URI into string array? Please advice